# CSS: Vertical align content of an element

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I need to vertical align a span, but the thing that makes this complicated is that this span needs to occupy its whole parent. Something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uaE6/)

So, the HTML is

```
<div>
    <span>OK</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: lightgrey;
}

span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Is this possible without changing the html ?

UPDATE: Although the below answers are all correct and interesting, I chose the one I actually used to be the correct one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell it to behave like a table:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: table;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9uaE6/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
div{ 
/* Internet Explorer 10 */
display:-ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-pack:start;
-ms-flex-align:center;

/* Firefox */
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack:start;
-moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:start;
-webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
display:box;
box-pack:start;
box-align:center; 
}
```

Source:[ms-flex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[**`your Updated Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uaE6/18/)

Comment: I need some time to understand what is going on here, thanks a lot for this example! I've changed your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uaE6/20/) a bit so that the OK is centered

Comment: This can be used for complex problems. here you have a single element. But If you would have some complex elements, you can give any alignment respect to the parent... Its good approach. I follow this. Some people may not like this. :) @JeanlucaScaljeri

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that with a 'ghost' pseudo element

```
span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

span:before {
    content: "";
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/9uaE6/11/